# Back button and neon-animated-pages

Tags: polymer-1.0

Having a contact list build with Polymer's `neon-animated-pages` ([Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dvtigzoJuOkVRUenwkHS?p=preview)), the navigation through them is clear. But using a mobile device for example, when hitting the back button, the complete page dissapears i.e. it 1) exits the application or 2) goes back to the previous page instead of the previous `neon-animated-page`.

Any change to achieve this behaviour to be navigating like a normal page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have a use a router like page.js and add history state whenever you are transitioning from one page to another. You can check out polymer-starter-kit on how this is done.